Issues sending audio with FFmpeg to a Deva DB RX 90-91
I want to send audio with FFmpeg to a Deva DB90/91 RX with RTP.
The file sent is an mp3 file 128 kbps stereo and 48KHz.
The command line :
ffmpeg -protocol_whitelist file,rtp,udp -i <file> -c copy -f rtp rtp://<IP DEVA>:<port DEVA>

I get something very strange.

On a DB90RX: it works for 1 second, then not for 1 second, etc…
On a DB91RX: it works for like 5 seconds, then it's over.

I got no error message from FFmpeg, but the result is awful.

Try adding -re argument: ffmpeg -re -protocol_whitelist...
